# Where each partition has only one value in the constraint column, can I avoid filtering?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, partitioning, postgresql-9.6

I have partitioned a table in postgres 9.6 by date.  Every date *within* a parition is identical.

When I select data, a relatively expensive `Seq Scan` `filter` operation happens against every row in the partition (see below). I know this is unecessary; is there a way I can point this out to the database?

```sql
prescribing@prescribing=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM rx WHERE rx.processing_date = '2018-11-01' 
[more] - > ;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                            QUERY PLAN                                             │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Append  (cost=0.00..230777.40 rows=9670673 width=62)                                              │
│   ->  Seq Scan on rx  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=128)                    │
│         Filter: (processing_date = '2018-11-01'::date)                                            │
│   ->  Seq Scan on rx_201811 rx_1  (cost=0.00..230777.40 rows=9670672 width=62) │
│         Filter: (processing_date = '2018-11-01'::date)                                            │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The tables are set up thus (with some extra columns omitted):

```
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│      Column       │         Type          │
├───────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ id                │ integer               │
│ processing_date   │ date                  │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
Child tables: rx_201801, rx_201802, ...etc...
```

```
Table "rx_201801"

┌───────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│      Column       │         Type          │
├───────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ id                │ integer               │
│ processing_date   │ date                  │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────────┘


Indexes:
    "cnstrt_rx_20101_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_rx_201701_date" btree (processing_date)

Check constraints:
    "rx_201801_processing_date_check" CHECK (processing_date >= '2018-01-01'::date AND processing_date < '2018-02-01'::date)
```

Comment: Could you add the index?

Comment: How is it Partitioned?

Comment: @MichaelKutz using the standard 9.6 "child"-table-with-constraints approach described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION

Comment: Is the filter really expensive? The query has to retrieve 10M rows. Checking the date value before sending the data sounds like some wasted CPU cycles but not too expensive compared.

Comment: Sure, it's all relative, but I have queries across 100 of these partitions so it adds up...